# CMSIS_OS2.c does not compile

Tags: c, freertos, cmsis

I am working on a C project using FreeRTOS but I would like to update it using the abstraction layer CMSIS_OS2.
Problem that is my FreeRTOS config file, I don't have all options enabled, so for example I am using only

```
#define configSUPPORT_STATIC_ALLOCATION       ( 1u )
#define configSUPPORT_DYNAMIC_ALLOCATION          ( 0u )
```

so all NONE dynamique functions are not compiled (example : xTaskCreate).

but in cmsis_os2.c, all functions must be present to compile

```
 if (mem == 1) {
      hTask = xTaskCreateStatic ((TaskFunction_t)func, name, stack, argument, prio, (StackType_t  *)attr->stack_mem,
                                                                                    (StaticTask_t *)attr->cb_mem);
    }
    else {
      if (mem == 0) {
        if (xTaskCreate ((TaskFunction_t)func, name, (uint16_t)stack, argument, prio, &hTask) != pdPASS) {
          hTask = NULL;
        }
      }
    }
```

So i don't know how to manage this issues since I don't want to enable all the FreeRTOSConfig.h options.

Any ideas whould be appreciated.

Jerome

Comment: Don't use CMSIS OS if it relies on dynamic task creation.

Comment: I am not using Dynamic task creation. I use only static but cmsis_os2.c need both functions to be defined (that is the problem)

Comment: Do you know that CMSIS RTOS can support what you want to do?

Comment: I assume, is it not very famous ?

Comment: CMSIS RTOS is well-known, but it's meant as an RTOS. You're essentially saying that you want to use the RTOS, but without compiling or using any RTOS functionality. CMSIS doesn't necessarily include the RTOS, but CMSIS RTOS is an RTOS.